# How to add order in $all operator in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can I get documents from mongo with an array containing some elements but IN THE SAME ORDER?

I know that `$all` do the job but ignoring the order of elements. The order in my case is important and I can't sort my arrays since it's describing a path that I want to keep the order.

111,222,333 is not the same as 222,111,333

Is there a way to do it using `$all` or maybe another operator in mongo aggregation framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the first "intersect" field, is just to give you back as debug what MongoDB make with this command. You should create the $and operator dynamically.

```
db.Test6.aggregate([
{ 
  $project: {
    _id:1,
    pages:1,
    intersect: {$setIntersection: [[111,666], "$pages"]},
    theCondition: {$let: {
      vars: {
      intersect: {$setIntersection: [[111,666], "$pages"]}
      },
      in: {
        $cond:[  {$and:[ 
                         {$eq:[{$arrayElemAt:["$$intersect", 0]}, 111]},
                         {$eq:[{$arrayElemAt:["$$intersect", 1]}, 666]}          
          ]} , true, false]
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
]);
```

Comment: That would be a good option if the elements are always adjacent. But in my case i don't know the index. Maybebi want path 333, 222, 666 but the array is 111,333,555,777,222,999,666 i want to get this array in my query since it has 333,233,666 not adjacent but in this order